# Android refresh IMediaPlaybackService current song content

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I make a simple example to let you understand what I need to do:

1) I open an unknown song (a song where I deleted all ID3 Tags) so IMediaPlaybackService don't have an user-friendly information

2) I update song information adding ID3 file

3) Current IMediaPlaybackService service don't have updated information about the current song and will always display old data, if I go to next song and than to prev song, it will have updated information.

But, is there a way to not use that workaround and tell to IMediaPlaybackService to refresh current song information?

Comment: probably no - stop, start, seek back to where you stopped might work

Comment: I think that user will "feel" this :)